# WAI-ARIA support for nested caption

Tags: gwt, vaadin, wai-aria

In Vaadin a button is rendered as the following HTML content:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" class="v-button v-widget" id="searchButton">
    <span class="v-button-wrap">
        <span class="v-button-caption">Search</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

As I read this caption "Search" will not be accessible to screen readers (they will have problem with reading it). 
However, when I test with Mac VoiceOver the caption is read correctly. Is it just a Mac VoiceOver correct support or am I missing something?

Comment: why will they have a problem reading it?

Comment: Here it is described: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/2891051 (section Very short intro)

Comment: Hi Adam, I tested it with JAWS 18 on Firefox 55, it announced the nested text as the accessible name, as expected. test file: https://codepen.io/stevef/pen/brybRQ am I missing something?

Comment: I do not have JAWS - I am just checking if I have aria-label or aria-labelledby correctly set. I also thought that this caption should not cause any problem but after I read the post given I was surprised but without opportunity to test it. If you tested it and it works as expected then I think the post from Vaadin is outdated. Thank you for help

Comment: In the case of the button role https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#button the accessible name (label) is provided by the text in the sub tree of the element with the role, therefore use of aria-label/labelledby is not required, although it could be used as an alternative naming method.